# ASP.Net and Flash animation: How to set the path?

Tags: asp.net, flash

I want to have a flash animation on my site.

When I insert a "http:..." adress in the field "Data" and "Value" in the code, its completly okay
But when I insert a "~/PATHHERE/FILEHERE.swf" in this fields, it don't function.

Code:

```
        <object data="~/Images/Flash/banner.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="936"
            height="142">
            <param name="movie" value="~/Images/Flash/banner.swf" />
        </object>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<object data='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/Flash/banner.swf") %>' type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="936" height="142">
    <param name="movie" value='<%= ResolveUrl("~/Images/Flash/banner.swf") %>' />
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume you want the ~ to refer to the application root. The problem is that the `<object>` tag doesn't know anything about the ~ trick; it is for asp.net server controls only. Try removing it - the '/' should refer to your app root (unless your are running in a virtual site on a dev computer). Or use a full url. Or a relative path (../images/whatever).